# What part of windows maps all these files to memory?

Tags: windows-10, performance, memory-management

Running sysinternals RamMap I can see that a huge number of files have been mapped into memory.  Some useful, sensible choices, but also lots of unnecessary rubbish; old installers in the Downloads folder that I have not used since they were downloaded, for example.

To be clear: I'm not concerned that these file mappings take up memory - my understanding is that, if processes need memory, these mappings will be sacrificed to make more available.  What I am concerned about is the amount of time I have to wait after the machine is restarted.  My old PC is slow at startup, and the cause of the slowness is 100% Disk, according to the performance tab of task manager.

I know that what I really need is a new machine, but it would help if I could prevent windows spending all its time mapping thousands and thousands of files to physical memory.

Or have I misunderstood what I am seeing?

thanks for any help

soakins

Comment: I don't know how that works and most don't, but since you mention getting a new machine. Why don't you try getting a new hard drive? Particularly an SSD one

Comment: Note that memory _mapping_ is a very different thing from having that file cached in physical memory. (Indeed it's meant to achieve the exact opposite – a "mapped" file is only read on demand.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information given by RamMap is not easy to read.

I suggest reading the article
[Introduction to the new Sysinternals tool: RAMMap](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap/ba-p/374717),
but here is a short explanation:

The Total size of "Mapped File" looks frightening, but it's bogus.

If you look under "File Summary" you will basically see almost every
file that you or any program has opened since boot, and indeed their
total size is pretty impressive.

However, you are only interested in the "Active" column, which is the amount
that is actually in memory and being used by some process.
The Total column is only history.

For example here is a screenshot from my computer :

[image]

The Total size is an impressive 50 GB, but Active is only 1.5 GB,
which I find quite reasonable.

Comment: So, when I look at the file summary tab, thousands of files are mentioned. Thousands! Are you saying that they have not all been accessed since reboot, for the express purpose of putting them in that list? Only the ACTIVE ones have been accessed, and the STANDBY ones have not been read in order to put them into the 'mapped files' list.

Comment: A memory mapped file is deceiving (as @harrymc points out) because those files were merely OPENED using CreateFileMapping() and as little as 4k was actually copied into memory.  It is the ***OPPOSITE*** of what you are thinking as far as the use, but indeed those files were all opened.  Memory mapping provides applications with a way of getting to a small segment of data in an extremely large file without having to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: These files were all opened at one time and are remembered. They may actively take zero RAM, but their size is remembered and added to the Total. They may have been opened by Windows components, by startup applications, even by the antivirus. But their size is still all added up in Total. Call them "ghost files".